# How to write in C# C structure with pointers

Tags: c#, c, c#-4.0

I have a following structure in C:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    int mode;
    unsigned char *fs;//a pointer to sbyte[16]  
    unsigned char *flist;//a pointer to sbyte[128]
    unsigned char *ival;//a pointer to sbyte[8] 
    unsigned char *ctx;//a pointer to sbyte[8]
    int fin; 
} mStruct;
```

And I need to write it in C#. I tried to define it like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1)]
public struct avGostParam
{
    public int mode;//a mode
    public IntPtr fs;// does char* converts to IntPtr?
    public IntPtr flist;//does char* converts to IntPtr?
    public IntPtr ival;//does char* converts to IntPtr?
    public IntPtr ctx;//does char* converts to IntPtr?
    public int fin;
}
```

But it's wrong way. Can you help me translate this into c#?

Comment: To use pointers I believe you'll have to mark your code as `unsafe` and allow unsafe code in your project's properties.

Comment: No, `IntPtr` doesn't require `unsafe` (don't ask why)... The code is correct.

Comment: Why do you need pointers?  Are you just trying to declare a struct with some arrays as members?  If so, use arrays, not pointers.

Comment: I'd imagine this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you want the members to be pointers?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you so much for answers! @George, yes, it can be XY problem (I'd like to use arrays as usual), but sadly it was my task to use pointers :(

Answer (score 1):

You need [fixed arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) in the structure.

Try this example where only the field `fs` is treated to managed string conversions via the `Fs` property.

```
public unsafe struct avGostParam
{
    public int mode;
    public fixed char fs[16];
    public fixed char flist[128];
    public fixed char ival[8];
    public fixed char ctx[8];


    public string Fs
    {
        get
        {
            fixed(char* ptr=fs)
            {
                return GetString(ptr, 16);
            }
        }

        set
        {                
            fixed(char* ptr=fs)
            {
                SetString(ptr, 16, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetString(char* ptr, int length)
    {
        char[] result=new char[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            result[i]=ptr[i];
        }
        return new string(result);
    }
    private static void SetString(char* ptr, int length, string value)
    {
        if(value.Length<length)
        {
            value=value.PadRight(length);
        }
        char[] items=value.ToCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            ptr[i]=items[i];
        }            
    }
}

unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var av=new avGostParam();

        av.Fs="ABCDEF";

        char* ptr=av.fs;
        for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(av.fs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

More on fixed buffers [here - Dot Net Perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fixed-buffer)

Comment: Thanks, it is what I needed!